# connecting webservice to sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net, web-services

net and im making a web service in which user get registered and then login . i have made a database . in which "ID ","Username","Password" . in webserive it show which user is login 
. this code is not working (name = reader[0].ToString();return name; ) name is red line . plz explain or do correction what is wrong where im mistaking

here is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Abdul Samad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\App_Data\webserver_database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" name="webconnectionstr"/>
</connectionStrings>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public int Register(string name , string password)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webconnectionstr"].ToString();
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into [userTable] (username,password) values
                    ('" + name + "','" + password + "')", connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return 1;
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {
                return 0;
            }
            finally 
            { 
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public int getUsername(int id)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webconnectionstr"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select username from [userTable] where userId='" + id + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               name = reader[0].ToString();
            }
            return cmd;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why u return cmd instead of name? The "getUsername" method must return string, not int. Could you please tell us which error gives you the code? And are you sure that the sql query returns data?

Comment: This code will be incredibly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. Also: don't store passwords in your database; store password _hashes_.

Comment: im new in this just doing for learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a string (Assuming you are trying to return the name from table.)

```
   [WebMethod]
        public string getUsername(int id)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webconnectionstr"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select username from [userTable] where userId='" + id + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string str = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               str = reader[0].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
            return str;

        }
```

Edit : A Better Option since you want only one value.

```
string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```